# xcode 4.3 sound will not play at app launch

Tags: xcode4.3

I have thoroughly looked through this forum and I have not found a solution to this issue.  When my app launches during the splash screen I want a 5 sec sound clip to play then stop when the app is done launching and the home screen is shown.

In the AppDelegate.m

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
NSURL *musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
pathForResource:@"bknewsroom2" 
ofType:@"caf"]];

AVAudioPlayer *launchClip = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];
[launchClip play];
```

Now I have a whole bunch of stuff loading within `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` this is just one of many things.  The sound won't launch in the simulator nor will it launch on my phone.  So am I missing something?  Again it is a 5 second clip that I want to play when the app launches for the first time.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue:

in the AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
//------ PLAY SOUND CLIP WHILE LOADING APP -----
NSLog(@"launch banner with clip");
NSURL *clip = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"soundfile" withExtension:@"caf"];
self.startupPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:clip error:NULL];
[self.startupPlayer play];
```

Now when the application launches, the sound clip plays. It does hiccup once which I'm looking into, but the function works.  Also, I put this at the top of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` if it was in the middle some place, it would work.